# Why doesn't Sign-in with Google require a Client Secret?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-signin, sign-in-with-google

I'm following Google's [new Sign In Button documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token?authuser=1#using-a-google-api-client-library). For the verification on server, they ask us to run the following code.(for NodeJS)

```js
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const client = new OAuth2Client(CLIENT_ID);
async function verify() {
  const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
      idToken: token,
      audience: CLIENT_ID,  // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend
      // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
      //[CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3]
  });
  const payload = ticket.getPayload();
  const userid = payload['sub'];
  // If request specified a G Suite domain:
  // const domain = payload['hd'];
}
verify().catch(console.error);
```

I find it weird that at no point, we specified the Client Secret, which was shown in our Google Developer console along with the Client ID.

Since the Client ID is also embedded in the frontend website code, anybody could essentially copy it, and start their own server on my credentials right?

When I looked at the `Oauth2Client2` constructor, it has the Client Secret as the second parameter, however it's optional.

```
(alias) new OAuth2Client(clientId?: string | undefined, clientSecret?: string | undefined, redirectUri?: string | undefined): OAuth2Client (+1 overload)
```

What is the logic behind this? Is not using the Client Secret on my server (as shown in the docs), creating a vulnerability on my site?

Comment: This is a public OAuth client, see the remark about "user-agent-based application" [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Ohh I see. Why does google suggest [having that piece of code on the server](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/verify-google-id-token?authuser=1#using-a-google-api-client-library) then?

Comment: That is for validating the access token that the public OAuth client has issued.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen What I mean to ask is, since it is a **public** OAuth client, what was the need to have that code running on the server. It is publicly available info right? Why not just run it on the client, and use the info, if you need to, somewhere else.

Comment: The OAuth client is public, but the access token that you receive after logging in to Google is, of course, secret.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen If a hacker stole a user's JWT from the client (assume some XSS), couldn't they independently decode it (since the google oauth library doesn't require any secret keys to decode)? I thought if the client secret is necessary to decode, then my users would be safe from hackers

Comment: JWTs are not _encrypted_, they are _signed_. So you can always decode them, but you cannot forge them. And if someone steals a bearer token (such as a JWT), they can make requests on your behalf, that's the nature of bearer tokens.